# How to work with xml in android?

Tags: android, xml

I am looking for a way to work with xml file in from android. By work I mean to edit the xml file so I can delete rows (tags with info) in it, edit and add new ones.

I found a lot of ways and got confused. Can some one tell me what is the best way to do it?
I need it so I can save info in it(like list of people with their details - so each person is an object).

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-android/)

Hope this helps!

Tjekkles

Comment: It shows only how to read the file and how to create it but it doesn't show how to edit it and how to delete tags (with info) from it...

Answer (score 0):

for saving information, I would recommend looking at http://www.xom.nu/, it is an extra library that you add on that will allow you to create and parse through xml files that are storing information. depending on what your using it for, you can also save it in the `strings.xml` file.